spring @joinColumn object not passing in html to controller
I,m noob in coding.
I coding based spring pet clinic.
now not passing object
<div th:replace="~{::caller-select('사이트', 'hstry_site', ${historySites})}"></div>
<div th:replace="~{::caller-select('유형', 'hstry_type', ${historyTypes})}"></div>
<div th:replace="~{::caller-input('문의 내용', 'hstry_content')}"></div>

'hstry_content' OK. but 'hstry_site' & 'hstry_type' is not pass.
chrome dev mode > network > formdata > 3 value all OK.
Can i know how to fix?
controller print object like below.
[History@23d723c8 hstry_id = [null], hstry_call_time = [null], hstry_content = '12312312', hstry_site = [null], hstry_type = [null], tel_no = '01000000001']
History class is below.
@Column(name = "hstry_content")
private String hstry_content;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "hstry_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private HistoryType hstry_type;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "hstry_site_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private HistorySite hstry_site;

when change Column info like
//  @Column(name = "hstry_type_id")
//  private Integer hstry_type;
//
//  @Column(name = "hstry_site_id")
//  private Integer hstry_site_id;

its passing to controller.

It seems like you're facing an issue with passing hstry_site and hstry_type objects in your Spring application, possibly related to Thymeleaf templates and form submission. Let's break down the steps to ensure these objects are correctly passed to your controller.
1. Thymeleaf Template Changes
Ensure that your Thymeleaf template (caller-select and caller-input fragments) correctly bind to hstry_site and hstry_type.
<!-- For hstry_site -->
<div th:replace="~{::caller-select('사이트', 'hstry_site', ${historySites})}"></div>

<!-- For hstry_type -->
<div th:replace="~{::caller-select('유형', 'hstry_type', ${historyTypes})}"></div>

<!-- For hstry_content -->
<div th:replace="~{::caller-input('문의 내용', 'hstry_content')}"></div>

Make sure that:

historySites and historyTypes are correctly populated in your controller model.
The dropdowns or select inputs correctly bind to hstry_site and hstry_type.

2. Controller Handling
In your controller method, ensure that you're correctly receiving and handling these objects.
@PostMapping("/saveHistory")
public String saveHistory(@ModelAttribute("history") History history) {
    // Check the values received in history object
    System.out.println(history);
    // Save logic or further processing
    return "redirect:/success"; // Redirect to success page or another endpoint
}

3. Entity Mapping
Ensure that your History entity correctly maps to HistorySite and HistoryType.
@Entity
public class History {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long hstry_id;

    @Column(name = "hstry_content")
    private String hstry_content;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "hstry_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private HistoryType hstry_type;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "hstry_site_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private HistorySite hstry_site;

    // Getters and setters
}

Ensure that HistoryType and HistorySite entities are correctly defined and mapped as well.
4. Cascading and ID Fields
If you change to using Integer fields directly (hstry_type_id and hstry_site_id), remember to update your entity and controller accordingly. This change might affect how you handle form submissions and database operations.
Summary
Double-check:

Thymeleaf templates for correct binding and dropdown/select options.
Controller method for correct @ModelAttribute handling.
Entity mappings and changes (especially if switching to direct ID fields).

By ensuring these steps, you should be able to correctly pass hstry_site and hstry_type objects to your controller and persist them in your database as intended.

solve this issue.
i added 'HistoryTypeFormmater', and 'HistorySiteFormmater'.
error reason is typeMismatch about 'history'..
Thanks for reply and helping to solve.
I can to know error reason for your '2. Controller Handling' method.

solve this issue.
public String processAddCallerForm(Caller caller, @Valid History history, BindingResult result, @PathVariable("tel_no") String tel_no) {
}

this code contain parameter 'BindingResult result'. so I can't catch error message in teminal, after delete 'BindingResult result', I can see error message like this :

Field error in object 'history' on field 'hstry_site': rejected value [리드인]; codes [typeMismatch.history.hstry_site,typeMismatch.hstry_site,typeMismatch. .......

petclinic have 'PetTypeFormatter.java', before typeMismatch, I don't have 'HistoryTypesFormatter.java' and 'HistorySitesFormatter.java'.
after added 'HistoryTypesFormatter.java' and 'HistorySitesFormatter.java'. solve typeMismatch.

Thanks to reply, and helping to solve.
